# Why use `std::map::find` for checking if maps have a key?

Tags: c++, algorithm, dictionary, find, stdmap

I recently found out (not through research, so if this is wrong please tell me and I will correct this) that the following somehow works:

```cpp
std::map<T*, U*> map;
std::cout << map[key_that_is_not_in_map] << std::endl;
// OUTPUT:
// 0
```

However a lot of people recommend using `std::map::find(key_.....) != std::map::end()`.

Is there something about the latter that makes it safer, or is the first only applicable to pointers keys and values?

Comment: `operator[]` requires a mutable map, because it adds the key to the map if it does not exist, with a zero-initialized value.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is there something about the latter that makes it safer, or is the
>   first only applicable to pointers keys and values?

**Yes**, `std::map::operator[]` performs an insertion if no key exists. And the [`std::map::find`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/find) does not.

From *cppreference.com* the [`std::map::operator[]`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/operator_at)

> Returns a reference to the value that is mapped to a key equivalent to
>   key, **performing an insertion if such key does not already exist**.

Comment: Oh so if the first is false, then is an entry is added?

Comment: @ChrisGeorge • `find` is a find, and `[key]` is an "upsert" (update if found, otherwise insert).